# Printing to Dot Matrix With HTML From Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, printing, applet, npapi

With NPAPI being faced out by Chrome, We've been trying to find a good alternative to an Applet we had for printing checks and invoices. There are many options, like NaCl and PNaCl from chrome (with PPAPI) however those really mean settling for chrome, which isn't a really good idea. Jumping from solution to solution we've found that it is possible to print absolute positions from HTML, like so:

```
<html style="font-family: courier new; font-size: 11pt;">
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:129mm; top:25mm"><<**.***,**>></div> <!-- PLC_POSICIONMTO -->
    <div style="position:absolute; left:30mm; top:38mm;">&#60;&#60;&#60;??????&#62;&#62;&#62;</div> <!-- PLC_POSICIONBENEFICIARIO -->
    <div style="position:absolute; left:40mm; top:44mm;"><<<<**.***,**>>>></div> <!-- PLC_POSICIONMTO1 -->
    <div style="position:absolute; left:20mm; top:56mm;">?????</div> <!-- PLC_POCISIONFECHA -->
    <div style="position:absolute; left:82mm; top:56mm;">???</div> <!-- PLC_POCISIONANO -->
    <div style="position:absolute; left:mm; top:mm;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:mm; top:mm;"></div> 
</body>
```

This is an example i made to test if the position works, those attributes will come from a DataBase. It all seems to work, however when trying to print from chrome to a dot matrix printer, the preview looks weirdly zoomed in, and doesn't print correctly, but when I print to a PDF and then to the Dot Matrix (or from firefox) it works like it shoul (somewhat). The page design in the Chrome Preview looks weird too, when the page is in portrait mode, it lookes squared, but in landscape mode it lookes as it should in vertical (and it seems to work fine until i print, where it prints as in landscape mode and not like the preview shows).

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?. Or is there another solution that doesn't force me to use chrome alone as he company's browser?.

Comment: FireBreath 2 (in the refactor branch) needs some polishing but supports NPAPI, ActiveX, and Native Messaging (chrome)

Comment: I read about FireBreath, but from what I understood it currently uses NPAPI or ActiveX, and since NPAPI is being faced out it doesnt really work right?, or am I mistaken? @taxilian

Comment: FireBreath 2 is in the refactor branch, not fully released yet; it has support for native messaging, and is a major refactor from the main firebreath codebase to make all I/O with the browser asynchronous so that the interface can be consistent.  It is not nearly as easy to get started as with firebreath 1.x, since it's not well documented or fully released, but it is being used in production already by several companies.  I am the primary developer for the FireBreath project, so I Know Of Which I Speak =]

Comment: Alright then, I'll check it out again, see if i can get it going. On the other side, I already have some tests going for the HTML option, do you have any input for that specifically?. It seems to be a chrome issue but still.

Comment: Just that my experience with print stylesheets and browsers is that it's very difficult to get it to work consistently; you could have an issue with viewport, or the zoom of the root page; you might try setting the width (in mm) of the html and body tags.  Also check zoom and other settings in the print dialog -- settings in the print dialog can have a huge impact on things

Comment: Alright!. I'll see if i can manage anything. I'll come back with any result i get just in case.